# Browse for a sound file in android

Tags: android, android-studio, audio

I am currently writing an app which simulates an incoming call.
I want to give the option to the user, to specify a sound file which will start playing when he accepts the call.
I want to make it simple for the user to browse his phone directory and specify a file.
I would like some suggestions for how to do it.(Not asking for the solution just some hints because I am fairly new to android programming.)
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put below codes in your project when you want to select audio.

```
public class SoundActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //for example you have a button that open SoundBrowser when trigger
    OpenSoundFileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            }
        });

     }

// override onActivityResult in the same Activity, as below

        @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

      if(requestCode == 1){

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            //the selected audio.
            Uri myUri = data.getData(); 

            //and by taken uri you can start your Media
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        }
      }
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a good answer but as I stated I am fairly new to android programming and I would appreciate if you could explain your code a bit more.
What I want to do is to display something like a file browser and then return a uri with the chosen file to my Activity which will use a MediaPlayer to play it.

Comment: @Dimitris the answer has been updated, let me know if it has any difficulty.

Comment: oh i think i get it now.
What you are saying is that I will have to create the browser activity and pass it to the created Intent (the one under onClick) and then I will get the result with the overriden onActivityResult method right?

Comment: @Dimitris no no no! by using : `Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);`  you ask android to open file browser which you specify just "audio", and you can select them. after selecting the audio it came back to your app where you can use the selected audio and for example play that. first of all please try code and you can see the magic happen.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much 
Sorry for the late feedback but I didn't had much time this month to continue my work on my app and I began working again today.